# Show ContextMenuStrip from ToolStripDropDown without dismissing ToolStripDropDown

Tags: .net, winforms, toolstrip

I have a `ToolStrip`.  In my `ToolStrip` I have a `ToolStripDropDownButton`.  My `ToolStripDropDownButton` has a DropDown of type `ToolStripDropDown` that contains a `ToolStripControlHost` which contains a `Label`.  I have assigned a `ContextMenuStrip` to my `Label`.  When I show the DropDown and right-click on the label, the `ContextMenuStrip` displays correctly, but the original DropDown is dismissed.

I can understand the existence of underlying code to prevent the display of two "ToolStripItems" at the same time and I'm assuming that's what I'm running in to here.  Anybody know of a way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this can be accomplished with creative use of the AutoClose property on the ToolStripDropDown class:

First, on Label Right Click, set AutoClose of the ToolStripDropDown to false and show context menu.
Second, on ContextMenu dismissal, reset AutoClose of the ToolStripDropDown to true.